# FreeTDS missing encryption support to connect to MS SQL

Tags: linux, gentoo, kerberos, sql, odbc

I'm running a Gentoo Linux and I'm trying to connect to MS SQL via `pyodbc` using `freetds`.

I enabled the debug log in `freetds`. Now when I try to connect I'm seeing this:

```
18:13:00.841828 13523 (net.c:270):tds_open_socket: connect(2) returned "Operation now in progress"
18:13:00.955976 13523 (net.c:310):tds_open_socket() succeeded
18:13:00.955996 13523 (util.c:156):Changed query state from DEAD to IDLE
18:13:00.956017 13523 (net.c:741):Sending packet
0000 12 01 00 34 00 00 00 00-00 00 15 00 06 01 00 1b |...4.... ........|
0010 00 01 02 00 1c 00 0c 03-00 28 00 04 ff 08 00 01 |........ .(......|
0020 55 00 00 02 4d 53 53 51-4c 53 65 72 76 65 72 00 |U...MSSQ LServer.|
0030 d3 34 00 00            -                        |.4..|

18:13:01.190745 13523 (net.c:555):Received header
0000 04 01 00 25 00 00 01 00-                        |...%....|

18:13:01.190772 13523 (net.c:609):Received packet
0000 04 01 00 25 00 00 01 00-00 00 15 00 06 01 00 1b |...%.... ........|
0010 00 01 02 00 1c 00 01 03-00 1d 00 00 ff 0a 32 10 |........ ......2.|

18:13:01.190781 13523 (login.c:1057):detected flag 3
18:13:01.190783 13523 (login.c:1068):server required encryption but support is not compiled in
18:13:01.190785 13523 (login.c:466):login packet rejected
18:13:01.190821 13523 (util.c:156):Changed query state from IDLE to DEAD
```

This sounds like the support for some encryption is missing, but I don't know which one. My `freetds` is complied with these configure parameters:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --datadir=/usr/share --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var/lib --disable-dependency-tracking --libdir=/usr/lib64 --with-tdsver=7.0 --enable-msdblib --enable-odbc --with-unixodbc=/usr --enable-krb5
```

As far as I know it's using `libkrb5` for the encryption. These are the configure flags for my `libkrb5`:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --datadir=/usr/share --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var/lib --libdir=/usr/lib64 --without-ldap --without-tcl --enable-pkinit --enable-thread-support --without-hesiod --enable-shared --with-system-et --with-system-ss --enable-dns-for-realm --enable-kdc-lookaside-cache --with-system-verto --disable-rpath  --with-pkinit-crypto-impl=openssl
```

Does somebody know which configure flags I'm missing to be able to connect to MS SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself, in the `freetds` configure parameters i was missing `--with-openssl`. Once I added that and reinstalled `freetds` everything worked fine.